# Mssql Instead of Update triggers null for values if no rows in view - Maybe Understanding Required

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is a logic question about Triggers I think.

We have a instead of update trigger on the view.

At present we have a webapp that runs a command like:

```
Update view set this=x, that = y where z='2323';
```

Sometimes the 2323 doesn't match a row in the view but it still runs the instead of update.

Alas the set values from "inserted" table are all NULL instead of x or y.

We have a little logic in the trigger that will also setup (insert) a new entry if it is not found.  It also inserts another row in another table (Audit).

How do I solve this issue where - NO records returned in the view = No values passed into the instead of trigger?

If it build like that by design, then what are my options, I guess to do a select in the webapp, and if a row exists call update else insert trigger, but this seems overkill.

Any clues?

Martin

Comment: the question is unclear and vague: please add details about the structure of the involved tables and some sample data with steps required to reproduce the issue. **wild guess**: wrong join in the view.

Comment: Diagnosis - your trigger is broken and assumes that `inserted` and `deleted` contain (at least) one row. That's not the case.

Comment: Thanks.  Ill look to see if I am assuming that.  But surely INSERTED should contain the value to insert (especially if its a INSTEA OF )?

Comment: As an additional note. I also removed a filter from the view too, in the hopes it was filtering extra, but its simply stands that UPDATE is called whether any rows are returned in the view or not, but if not, the actual values are all NULL from the SQL statement.  Is there another table type except INSERTED and DELETED that im missing?

Comment: Can I ask a simple question. Maybe I just need to rethink the TRIGGER.  I want to run an update statement, even if there is nothing to update because the trigger needs to also do an INSERT in another table elsewhere using some of the fields passed?

Comment: Ok here is the SQL for the VIEW first:
SELECT        dbo.v_Person.firstname_name, dbo.v_Payment.amount, dbo.v_Payment.payment_date, dbo.v_Employment.staff_number FROM            dbo.v_Person INNER JOIN                         dbo.v_Payment ON dbo.v_Person.eid = dbo.v_Payment.person_eid INNER JOIN                         dbo.v_Employment ON dbo.v_Person.eid = dbo.v_Employment.eidWHERE        (dbo.v_Payment.payment_method_guid = '8ac9c7e9-0f32-4b22-9223-33f36e50a2cb')

Comment: Now the Trigger, if I can paste...

Comment: Alas its too long, so Ill paste a little

Answer (score 0):

While the question is a bit vague, I can suggest to architect it other way around - create `instead of insert` trigger, and write your logic inside. This way you'll always have a record in the `inserted` table.

So if there's no record - you'll insert your data into underlying tables, otherwise - run an update.

```
create table test (name nvarchar(128) primary key, value int);

create trigger utr_test on test
instead of insert
as
begin
    set nocount on

    update test set
        value = i.value
    from test as t
        inner join inserted as i on
            i.name = t.name

    insert into test (
        name,
        value
    )
    select
        i.name,
        i.value
    from inserted as i
    where
        not exists (
            select * from test as t where t.name = i.name
        )
end
```

Then you can try this:

```
insert into test values ('Test', 1);

select * from test;

insert into test values('Test', 2);

select * from test;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, as I thought the same.  I setup a Instead of Insert too but it only calls the Update instead trigger.  I don't think SQL plays it safe, and if there is nothing to update doesn't assume its an insert.  After all I did call UPDATE in SQL not INSERT.  Any other theories?

Comment: That's the point - you have to run insert then instead of update. Then you'll always have your data

Comment: But how do we know if we need to update or insert?  DO I need to do a pre-select from the WebApp to know if there is already a row or not?

Comment: you can always check in the trigger if you have record with `z='2323'` in the table. If you do - then update, if not - insert

Comment: That what we ended up doing.  Its just that I thought we could run the triggers like SP and do multiple SQL statements irrespective to whether or not a row actually was updated.  We know do exactly what you suggested (in the webapp), we select, then insert or update accordingly.  Many thanks  Martin

Comment: @WebForcesLtd it seems that you still check before update/insert. Check updated answer pls